# Trying to Run a Program from another user's Database

Tags: batch-file

I have a program that has different databases for each user. 
I need it to run always with the database of a specific user as default. 
This is possible with using "Shift + Right click" and selecting it to "Run as a different user". 
However I prefer this would happen automated.

To make this easier I've tried creating a batch file to access the program via psexec.
The program runs, however I get the error: "Open Database error" at first and then "Cannot find the file C:\Windows\System32\Cardlock.mdb" after you click the first error ok.
The database file he asks for is on the same directory as the program.

This is my code:

```
setlocal
cd /d "%~dp0"
psexec \\Feels -u FLH1\Feelslikehome -p password "C:\Program Files (x86)\proUSBHotelCardSystem\CardLock.exe"
```

Could you guys help me to run the program with the other users Database?

Thanks

Comment: Seems seeing as `cmd` was launched from `%__AppDir__%` it is assuming that the `Carlock.mdb` file would also be there.

Comment: change the code to try to change the working directory but didn't work. thank you for the quick replay @GerhardBarnard